# Axios get request inside setInterval() stops executing after a while even if setInterval() is working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am writing a code to sync youtube videos on 2 different devices(or a different browser) using React and Node.js. In the react code, I am sending get request to the server every second to get the state of the video player. Now, setInterval() is working properly - calling controlPlayer() every second and if I pause or play the video on one device, the video pauses and plays correctly on the other device. But, after a while the axios get request stops executing even though setInterval() calls the function properly - specifically the code inside try block.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

/*eslint-disable eqeqeq*/
function App() {
  var player;
  var playerState;
  const opts = {
    height: '450',
    width: '800',
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      origin: window.location,
    },
  };

  const onPlayerReady = (event) => {
    player = event.target;
  }

  const onStateChange = async () => {
    playerState = player.getPlayerState();
    //setPlayerState()
    try {
      await axios.put('/api/setplayerstate', { playerState });
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const controlPlayer = async () => {
    console.log('out');
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/getplayerstate');
      playerState = data.playerState;
      console.log('in');
      if(playerState == 1) {
        player.playVideo();
      }
      else if(playerState == 2) {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
      else{
        player.pauseVideo();
        console.log(playerState);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(controlPlayer, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div id='player'>
      <YouTube
      id='video'
      videoId='JXeJANDKwDc'
      opts={opts}
      onReady={onPlayerReady}
      onStateChange={onStateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

var playerState = -1;

app.put('/api/setplayerstate', (req, res) => {
    playerState = req.body.playerState;
});

app.get('/api/getplayerstate', (req, res) => {
    console.log(playerState);
    res.send({ playerState });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5000');
});
```

What am I missing here? Or is there a different logic to implement this?

Comment: Ask yourself: what happens when that (axios) async call will takes longer than one second?

Comment: Your browser won't send more than a very few requests in parallel to one domain at a time. Probably your nodejs server is taking some time to respond and then requests  queues up and browser throttles. Look into [socket.io](https://socket.io/), this is a perfect use case and easy to do with it. If you can't use it for some reason, change your logic to use setTimeout and do it after each call is completed.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky Oh I haven't thought of that. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @MatJ Oh then that must be it. I'll try socket.io now.